# redirect to folder without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am having trouble with redirecting the main domain to a subdirectory without changing the URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kargomastercompanies\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.kargomastercompanies\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/kargomastercompanies\.com\/kargomastercompanies\.com" [R=301,L]
```

that's the code written in .htaccess file. What should I do to keep the domain name same as it's in my root directory?
Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply rewrite, without redirecting, you should not use [R=301]

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?kargomastercompanies\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^kargomastercompanies\.com /kargomastercompanies.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,L]
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache or try with other browser ?

Comment: I want to redirect but I want my site to show kargomastercompanies.com/
Instead of [link](kargomastercompanies.com/kargomastercompanies.com/)

Comment: The name for that is "rewrite", not "redirect". If you redirect, the url change. It's what my htacess do.

Comment: One more thing what if someone clicks a link on my site?

Comment: It worked but I'm having some problems. Like if I try to login into admin panel through http://example.com/wp-admin   
Then it redirects to old URL.